# How to set Fullscreen when playing video on android in Livecode?

Tags: android, livecode

I create player for playing with android.

This code on my card:

```
on opencard
   --start videomobile
   if the environment is "mobile"then
      mobileControlCreate "player","videoControl"
      mobileControlSet "videoControl","filename","assets/player/vdo.mp4"
      mobileControlSet "videoControl","preserveAspect",true
      mobileControlSet "videoControl","showController",true
      mobileControlSet "videoControl","visible",true
      mobileControlSet "videoControl","rect",the rect of player ID 1004
   end if
   --end videomobile
end opencard
```

When I tested on my device. The video has show and playing. But It's not Fullscreen like on iOS.

How do I do?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, the full screen option is only available for iOS with LiveCode.  You can manually adjust the rect of the player though with the mobileControlSet command.